# Describe the structure of the ring $(ℤ/2ℤ)[α]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R = (ℤ/2ℤ)[α]$ for $α$ satisfying $α^2 + α + 1 = 0.$ Describe the structure of this ring.

I have gotten as far as saying that this can be considered the quotient ring $(ℤ/2ℤ)[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ but I'm pretty stumped on where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is a good start. A good way to follow up might be to find the number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by interpreting $R$ as a vector space. Your restriction $\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$ gives a hint that any power of $\alpha$ larger than or equal to $2$ can be written as a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $1$.

Thus, this ring, additively, is isomorphic to the vector space $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.

For the multiplicative part, you can figure out by writing down the multiplicative table. Since there is only 4 elements in the ring, I think that is rather easy.

Hope I helped. If you need extra help on the multiplicative part, I can write down that part for you.

Thanks for Tobias's comment. I have not reached a rep of 50 so I cannot reply, but changing $\alpha^k$ to $R$ is definitely necessary.

Comment: I think you mean $R$ instead of $\alpha^k$ at the start.